# Why is my coding not working? Trying to show data in richtextbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have spent hours trying to fix this problem I have, basically I want to only display column 1 from my text file in my rich text box.

Each column is seperated by a space (" ")

When I run the following coding it shows all columns.

```
RichTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Path")
    Dim str1() As String = Nothing
    Dim LinesList2 As New List(Of String)

    For Each line1 In LinesList2
        str1 = line1.Split(" "c)
        If str1(0) = line1 Then
            Dim Hold As String = Nothing
            Hold = line1 & " " & str1(1).ToString
            LinesList2.Add(Hold)
        End If
    Next
    LinesList2.Sort()

    For Each Str As String In LinesList2
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(Str & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
```

Comment: You're reading the entire file into tyour richtextbox, then then looping through an empty list (LinesList2) twice. Everything after the first line does [essentially] nothing because the list is always empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easier using LINQ:

```
Dim firstColumnText = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines(path)
                      Select line.Split(" "c)(0)
RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, firstColumnText)
```

Apart from that you're using an empty list here:

```
' reads the whole file and set it as text for the RichTextBox '
RichTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)
' creates an empty List(Of String) '
Dim LinesList2 As New List(Of String)
' "Iterates" the empty list '
For Each line1 In LinesList2
    '  .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading anything into LinesList2, so nothing inside either loop gets executed. Even if you did, the line `Hold = line1 & ...` seems to include the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the whole line

```
    Hold = line1 & " " & str1(1).ToString
    LinesList2.Add(Hold)
```

And what is the purpose of ?

```
str1(0) = line1
```

That is only going to be true if there was no split.

You need to debug line1 and sr1()

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're missing code, you have created `LinesList2` but not filled it with anything therefore there is nothing to loop through.